# mysql - timestamp column of another column value change

Tags: mysql, timestamp

Say I have a mySQL table of a few columns:

**id, name, job, jobUpdatedAt**

Whenever specifically the *job* column changes, I want mySQL to automatically update the timestamp of *jobUpdatedAt*. (so if only name changes, it does not update)

Is such thing possible?

Thanks

Comment: You would probably need a trigger for this, if you want to handle purely from MySQL.  Otherwise, you could create application logic which does the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
BEFORE UPDATE
ON table_name
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.jobUpdatedAt = CASE WHEN OLD.job = NEW.job
                            THEN OLD.jobUpdatedAt
                            ELSE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                            END;
```

`jobUpdatedAt` will be renewed only when `job` is updated by fact.

`jobUpdatedAt` will be saved if the query should try to update it explicitly.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1b48bce653eb9a1d778e406fa5af894a

Comment: `WHEN OLD.job <=> NEW.job` would also account for a null value.

Comment: @forpas True. But I doubt that OP needs in this... if so he will edit.

Comment: @Akina Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. Google yielded no results, probably because I didn't know how to even call it.